# Do I need to build a web form to use this web call?

Tags: web, call

When I replace the two options in this web call directly in the URL, I don't get the expected results.

https://secure.trademark-clearinghouse.com/tmch/public/labels?name=a%26b&jurisdiction=BX

Do I need to build a web form to use this web call?

Or am I replacing the options incorrectly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using URL parameters to send some information
name=a%26b&jurisdiction=BX
means:
parameterName=parameterValue separed by "&" symbol.
in your case:
name="aɫb"
jurisdiction="BX"
If you want to just read that, will work without a form.
Any further explanation we will need more information about what do you want to do. But this symbol between the "a" and "b" is strange. As you can see here http://www.nicolas-hoffmann.net/utilitaires/codes-hexas-ascii-unicode-utf8-caracteres-usuels.php the code %26b is "ɫ" if you really want this in your data... it's okay.